# Android AWS S3 - Objects "don't exist" after upgrading sdk version from "2.2.+" to "2.6.7"

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have code for an Android app that uses S3. I had set it up almost a year ago following [this example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html), where, in the app dependencies, it declares:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+'
}
```

The current version at the time of writing this is [2.6.7](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Now, my problem is:

```
//This code came from the Mobile Hub sample application

//Obtain a reference to the mobile client. It is created in the Application class.
final AWSMobileClient awsMobileClient = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient();

//Obtain a reference to the identity manager.
IdentityManager identityManager = awsMobileClient.getIdentityManager();

AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(identityManager.getCredentialsProvider());

try{

    //This used to return TRUE but now returns FALSE
    boolean objectExists = s3Client.doesObjectExist(BUCKET_NAME, key);

    ...
//catch, etc.
```

Consequently, I am unable to download objects. I assume that this is somehow an authentication-related issue, and in following security principles is just telling me the object doesn't exist.

Nothing about the bucket name or keys has changed on either end, and I verified that the issue can be triggered and resolved by changing:

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+' //works
```

to

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.7' //does not work
```

and rebuilding/running the app.

I'm unable to find anything in the documentation or anything about changes in versions that would cause this. Does anyone know? I've yet to see how high I can go in version without this problem occurring.

EDIT: 2.3.9 works fine, [2.4.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#release-240-03212017) is where the problem arises. I can't ascertain which of those changes could cause the issue.

Comment: Is the AWSMobileClient and IdentityManager that you are referring part of the sample application downloaded from AWSMobileHub?

Comment: Yes. I should've mentioned that.

Comment: The AWSMobileClient and IdentityManager were removed from the AWS Mobile Hub Sample App on 08/31. The IdentityManager is released as part of the SDK. You can grab it at "aws-sdk-android-auth-core:2.6.0@aar". AWSMobileClient is released in "aws-sdk-android-mobile-client:2.6.7@aar" with minimal support for Authentication and SignInUI. The sample code you pointed out will not work with version of SDK >= 2.6.0.

Comment: I have added the answer to fix your code if you want to use version >= 2.6.0. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using version >= 2.6.0,

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-core:2.6.0@aar') { transitive = true; }
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.0'
}
```

1) Create an instance of IdentityManager:

```
import com.amazonaws.mobile.config.AWSConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager;

IdentityManager idm = new IdentityManager(getApplicationContext(), new AWSConfiguration(getApplicationContext()));
IdentityManager.setDefaultIdentityManager(idm);
```

2) Use it with S3Client.

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(IdentityManager.getDefaultIdentityManager().getCredentialsProvider());

try{

    //This used to return TRUE but now returns FALSE
    boolean objectExists = s3Client.doesObjectExist(BUCKET_NAME, key);

    ...
//catch, etc.
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out when I can. Is it always "safe" to use compile the auth-core dependency as transitive? As in, will I ever need to not do that?

Comment: Since it's an aar file, you have to add "transitive=true;" to pull in the dependencies automatically. The only dependency of auth-core is aws-android-sdk-core. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-auth-core/pom.xml